# tail -f, Determine if a file is no longer being written to

Tags: files, tail, open-files

I am using `tail -f` to follow the growth of a log file. I am having trouble finding a way to detect if the process that is writing to the log file (when it crashes or is otherwise terminated) is no longer accessing or writing to the file.

Here is the script I am using

```
tail -f log_file | while read LOGLINE
do
  echo -e "${LOGLINE}"
  if [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *ERROR* ]] ; then
  echo -e "ERROR FOUND : ${LOGLINE}\n"

  # handle the error here

  fi
done
```

What is the easiest and most efficient way to detect that the process writing to the log file has stopped (or that tail -f is no longer recieving input) and echo a message to screen alerting me of the event?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313486/detecting-when-a-log-is-no-longer-being-written-to-tail-f

Answer (score 7):

At least if you are running Linux you are doing this backwards. You should use `inotify` to react to the file being written.

```
#!/bin/sh
while inotifywait -qe modify filename
do

done
```

that will do.

Answer (score 6):

To obtain the process IDs of all processes which have your log file open, use `lsof`:

```
lsof -Fp /path/to/your/logfle
```

Note that this will only show processes which actually have the file open.  You may miss programs that keep the file closed except the brief instants when they actually need to write to it.

`lsof` is script-friendly and has many options.  See `man lsof`.

Here is a script which will write a message to the screen once there are no processes with your log file open:

```
while lsof -Fp /tmp/mylogfile  >/dev/null
do
    sleep 1
done
echo "No processes have the log file open"
```

There is a catch to the above: your `tail -f` process will have the file open.  You may want instead to show the message when the number of processes with that file open drops below two:

```
while [ "$(lsof -Fp /tmp/mylogfile | wc -l)" -ge 2 ]
do
    sleep 1
done
echo "There are less than two processes with the log file open"
```

Comment: On my laptop, lsof is making more than 27000 systems call at each loop. I don't know if it's considered clean scripting, nowadays things are changing so fast.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
PROC=apache2 # insert your process name here

while true; do
    pgrep $PROC > /dev/null # hides pgrep's output
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo "Call 911 $PROC died!" 1>&2 # redirects to stderr
        exit
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

So call this something like `lifealert.sh` and run it in the background like so `./lifealert.sh &`

When the if statement fires it will print to stderr, which you should see in your terminal while you're tailf-ing a file.